# Random loss of data in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I had a table in a SQL database that had around 30,000,000 records. I had been working with this table for a while and for whatever reason my laptop shutdown overnight and when I turned it back on, the same table had around 2,500,000 records. I checked and they were all the oldest 2.5 million, so all of the rows past a certain point were gone. I ran mysqlcheck on the db and it said it was OK, and repair table did nothing. What could have happened, and is there any way I can get my data back?

I should add that I committed after every insert, as always, and I'd had this table working at 30,000,000 records or so for a while.

Thanks

Comment: I believe if MySQL engine is MyISAM based then large data file could corrupt it. what is your MySQL Table Configuration ?  ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614541/whats-the-difference-between-myisam-and-innodb