# Can not able to set foreign key in mysql db using SqlYog

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

Getting error while setting foreign key to table as shown in image.

> Database Version: MySql 5.6

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Engine to InnoDB

[image]

Check the difference between MyISAM and InnoDB here to make suitable decision for your database design

[What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam)

[MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb)

[What's the difference between MyISAM and InnoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614541/whats-the-difference-between-myisam-and-innodb)