# In mysql database which table store as MyISAM type and which table store as InnoDB type ? And Why?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am using Both types in my database. And Found information regarding these two types as i given following :
1. InnoDB locks the particular row in the table, and MyISAM locks the entire MySQL table.
2. MyISAM is the original storage engine. It is a fast storage engine. It does not support transactions. 
3. InnoDB is the most widely used storage engine with transaction support. It is an ACID compliant storage engine.

So, I am confused on which table store as MyISAM type and which table store as InnoDB type in My database.
Please provide suggestion to me.

Comment: Use InnoDB for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyISAM` and `InnoDB` are two database engines, and they both are better in their aspects. `MyISAM` works best on non-transactional purpose such as where you need `SEARCH`. `InnoDB` works better where you use transaction such as `INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE`.

**The main difference between** `InnoDB` and `MyISAM` **is transaction and referential integrity**

They are both better in their own design goals.

[Refer to this link to have a clear idea about MyISAM and InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614541/whats-the-difference-between-myisam-and-innodb)