# Problem with entity deletion and foreign key constraint violation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony6

First of all, I'm quite a beginner with Symfony and Doctrine and I'm working on the final project of my formation.

In this project, I allow user to create Event with an unique Game associated to it. To do so, I have a Game entity related to an Event entity with a OneToMany relationship and I want that when I delete a specific Game, all the Event related to it set the field "event_game_id" to null in the db.

Here is my code :

Event entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EventRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EventRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity('eventName')]
class Event
{
    ...

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'events')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true, onDelete: 'SET NULL')]
    private ?Game $eventGame = null;

    ...
}
```

Game Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\GameRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: GameRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity('gameName')]
class Game
{
    ...

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'eventGame', targetEntity: Event::class)]
    private Collection $events;

    ...
}
```

And the GameController for the deletion :

```
    /**
     * Delete an existing game
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/admin/game/delete/{id}', name: 'game.delete', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function delete(EntityManagerInterface $manager, Game $game): Response
    {
        $manager->remove($game);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('game.index');
    }
```

I've tried multiple thing, putting the onDelete option litterally everywhere I could but I always get the error :

"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gamesandfriends`.`event`, CONSTRAINT `FK_3BAE0AA761D870AA` FOREIGN KEY (`event_game_id`) REFERENCES `game` (`id`))"

I've looked on multiple subject and in the doc but I'm certainly missing something because nothing worked.

Thank you in advance for your time and your advice !

Comment: There are two options.  1. Remove the constraint (not recommended) 2. Listen to the error and first delete the record linked in gamesandfriends before deleting the game itself.

Comment: Hi !
For what I understand of your solution, you suggest me to delete the events linked to the game before deleting the game itself ?
Because if it is this, I can't do that because I have this problem specifically because I want to keep the Event, only setting the eventGame to null.

Comment: You can also set the eventGame to null! But if you remove the record with it's id linked somewhere else, sql prevents it because of the FK constraint. I would really advise you to look at this post/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358986/disable-doctrine-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: Ok, I don't know if I'm stupid or what, but I've added (onDelete: 'SET NULL') on the Game entity and it worked ! I could swear I've already tried it but it seems I don't.

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The error message you are getting means that you are trying to delete a Game entity that has Events associated with it. The foreign key constraint on the `event_game_id` column in the event table prevents you from doing this.

To fix this, you need to set the `onDelete` option on the `eventGame` association in the `Event` entity to `SET NULL`. This will tell Doctrine to set the `event_game_id` column to `NULL` in the event table when the `Game` entity is deleted.

Here is the updated code for the Event entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EventRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EventRepository::class)]
#[UniqueEntity('eventName')]
class Event
{
    ...

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'events')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true, onDelete: 'SET NULL')]
    private ?Game $eventGame = null;

    ...
}
```

Once you have updated the code, you should be able to delete the Game entity without any errors.

Here is a breakdown of what the onDelete option does:

`CASCADE`: Deletes all child entities when the parent entity is deleted.
`SET NULL`: Sets the foreign key column in the child entity to NULL when the parent entity is deleted.
`RESTRICT`: Prevents the parent entity from being deleted if there are any child entities.
`NO ACTION`: Does nothing when the parent entity is deleted.
The default value for the onDelete option is `CASCADE`. However, in this case, we want to set the `event_game_id` column to `NULL` when the `Game` entity is deleted, so we use the `SET NULL` option.