# Spring @Transactional and rollback not working, spring integration tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I'm doing an integration test in spring and in this example I testing a service layer.

I have a problem where during the addition test in the service, rollback not working, and always add an item to the base ,but not delete it.

I put annotation @ Transactional and @ TestPropertySource on test class,
also have application-test.properties and the test is successful but the rollback is not executed and a new item is always added to the test database.

My test class and test method for add address(last one):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TicketServiceApplication.class)
@Transactional
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class AddressServiceIntegrationTest {


@Autowired
private AddressService addressService;

@Autowired
private AddressRepository addressRepository;

@Test
public void findAllSuccessTest(){
    List<Address> result = addressService.finfAllAddress();

    assertNotNull(result);
    assertFalse(result.isEmpty());
    assertEquals(2, result.size());
}

@Test
public void findOneAddressExistTest_thenReturnAddress(){
    Long id = AddressConst.VALID_ID_ADDRESS;
    Address a = addressService.findOneAddress(id);
    assertEquals(id, a.getId());
}

@Test(expected = EntityNotFoundException.class)
public void findOneAddressNotExistTest_thenThrowException(){
    Long id = AddressConst.NOT_VALID_ID_ADDRESS;
    Address a = addressService.findOneAddress(id);
}

@Test
public void addAddressSuccessTest(){

    int sizeBeforeAdd = addressRepository.findAll().size();

    Address address = AddressConst.newAddressToAdd();
    Address result = addressService.addAddress(address);

    int sizeAfterAdd  = addressRepository.findAll().size();

    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals(sizeBeforeAdd+1, sizeAfterAdd);
    assertEquals(address.getCity(), result.getCity());
    assertEquals(address.getState(), result.getState());
    assertEquals(address.getNumber(), result.getNumber());
    assertEquals(address.getLatitude(), result.getLatitude());
    assertEquals(address.getLongitude(), result.getLongitude());
    assertEquals(address.getStreet(), result.getStreet());
}
}
```

My application-test.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kts_test&useSSL=false&
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

And when execute add address test, every time in my kts_test data base ( db used for testing) is added new item and not rollback.

This is a log from the console where you can see that the rollback was called but did not execute, because when I refresh the database after the test the new item was left, it was not deleted.

```
INFO 10216 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@3e58a80e testClass = AddressServiceIntegrationTest, testInstance = com.ftn.services.address.AddressServiceIntegrationTest@4678ec43, testMethod = addAddressSuccessTest@AddressServiceIntegrationTest, testException = [null],...
```

Lastly, to write that I tried @Transactional above methods, I also tried @ Rollback above methods or @ Rollback (true), tried changing application-test.properties and I no longer know what the error might be.

If anyone can help I would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: What storage engine do you use in MySQL?

Comment: When I go with show engines, I get InnoDB is  Default.

Comment: But now I go with SHOW TABLE STATUS, and Engine is MyISAM !

Comment: Jap, but Hibernate can create tables with a different engine depending on dialect. You can try to set this: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Comment: Ok,  I try what you told me wright now. I add dialect to prperties file and again not rolleback.

Comment: Have the tables been recreated with InnoDB?

Comment: I forgot, but now I've recreated them and now changed the engine and made the rollback work. You saved me.
I will check for this to solve my problem.

Comment: Great, happy to help. .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate is by default creating tables with MyISAM storage engine - this engine does not support transactions. You need to have InnoDB tables:

- Either manage your DB migrations manually with a tool like Flyway (imho preferred option so you can have a complete control) and turn off recreating database in tests.
- Or set the correct engine in configuration:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
```

OR (deprecated)

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: will there be problems with the application if i change the engine to innodb in both data base and the application base and the test base?

Comment: What problems do you have in mind? If you are concerned about a different behavior / capabilities there are some answered questions about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614541/whats-the-difference-between-myisam-and-innodb
Hopefully it  will help. .)